# CSS Flexbox dynamic aspect-ratio code is influenced by content

Tags: css, flexbox

For a webpage grid-layout I decided to use Flexbox. Now I wanted to implement some "auto-functionality", so that grid-boxes can later be inserted without the need to add classes or styles in the HTML. One of this features is to make a box allways be 75% as tall as it is wide - even if the box is resized by, for example, browserwindow resize. Off course, if the boxes content extends the 75%-height, it should (and only then should) increase its height to fit the content. I searched for hours to find a suitable solution, but I finally got it working. So I thought at least, until I added content to the box.

The auto aspect-ratio works fine, as long as the box is empty. If I add content, the 75% of the width is  allways added to the height it has through extension by its content. I made a jsfiddle to clearly visualize the problem:

[JSFiddle wd5s9vq0](https://jsfiddle.net/wd5s9vq0/), visualizing the following Code:

**HTML-Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-cell"></div>
    <div class="content-cell"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content-cell">
        This cell has an inreased height because of
        it's content. The empty space below the
        content is the 75% of the cells width.
    </div>
    <div class="content-cell"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
}

.content-cell {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    margin: 10px;

    background-color: #ccc;
}

.content-cell::after {
    content: "";

    display: block;
    padding-top: 75%;
}
```

If I didn't knew it better, it looks like a floating-problem - but I think the `::before` / `::after` selector should add the block-element before the element it is used on and not inside it.

Does anyone has an idea on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a very widespread problem on the internet, and most solutions you find are either about wrapping the content, absolute-positioning the content or a mixture of both. This has numerous and case-dependent downsides. After hours of playing around with the code, I finally found a combination of CSS proporties that work without the need to add any DOM or make the content absolute-positioned. This looks quit basic, and I am wondering why it took me so long and why you can't find it out there on the web.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="mybox aspect-full">
    This is text, that would normally extend the box downwards.
    It is long, but not so long that it extends the intended aspect-ratio.
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.mybox {
    width: 200px;
}

.aspect-full::before {
    content: '';

    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

The only downside I could find is that the content of your cell must float. If you use `clear` on one of your child objects, it is positioned below the expander-block and you are back to the original problem. If you need to clear the floating of divs inside of these aspect-ratio-cells, you might consider to wrap them and keep the wrapper floatable.